# LinkButton with ID causes no postback, it does without

Tags: c#, asp.net

**Problem:**

When I click my linkbutton the form gets submitted, but it doesn't execute the postback function. It also doesn't execute the click function. These two don't get hit at all.

**Workaround**

Remove the ID from the linkbutton. In this case the click function get executed.

---

The button is dynamically added through this code:

```cs
LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
l.CssClass = "clause show-modalbox";
l.Click += clauseButton_Click;
l.Visible = true;
l.ID = "LinkButton_0";
l.Text = "C";
```

EDIT: I changed the ID to a static string, so that on postback the ID will be guaranteed the same.

EDIT 2: From the comments below: My Page_Init and Page_Load are not executed either on postback, they are properly executed when I leave out the ID of the button however.

EDIT 3: I was convinced this problem was related to my code because it didn't happen on other pages. Because of this I left out two important details:

1. The page has a masterpage
2. The content was rendered inside an updatepanel

See my answer below for the solution.

Comment: I just tried to change l.Click += clauseButton_Click; to l.Click += new EventHandler(clauseButton_Click);

No succes

Comment: Are you dynamically creating the control with a `.NewGuid()` each and every time?  That's not going to help, it needs to be the same thing on the post-back.

Comment: @freefaller I edited my post and code according to your comment. It didn't make a difference

Comment: Are you **re**-adding the dynamic control on the post-back?

Comment: Yes I am, the strange part is that both page_init and page_load are not even executed when clicking the control. In my page_load I re-add the control to the page

Comment: If the `page_init` and `page_load` are not being called, there is something more fundamentally wrong with the page.  You need to figure out why that is not happening first (redirection to a different page, etc)

Comment: But if something is fundamentally wrong, shouldn't the init and load function also not be called when I leave out the ID of the button. To me it seems as if there is somewhere a handler mismatch. I checked autoeventwireup and this is set to true, I have no real clue where to look from here.

Comment: Sometimes the strangest problems have the easiests fixes: On the page I had a scriptmanager with partial rendering enabled, once I disabled this the page_load function triggers, as well as the click function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my problem was that on the associated masterpage there existed a script manager, with EnablePartialRendering=true. Once I changed this to false, like below, it all worked.

```
<ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMasterPage" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="false"></ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the same ID as before, otherwise events aren't triggered.

```
LinkButton l = new LinkButton();
l.CssClass = "clause show-modalbox";
l.Click += clauseButton_Click;
l.Visible = true;
l.ID = "LinkButton_" + consecutiveNumber.ToString();
l.Text = "C";
```

Comment: I tried this solution in this way: limit the loop to only one execution, change the ID to LinkButton_0. Still nothing.

Comment: Sometimes the strangest problems have the easiests fixes: On the page I had a scriptmanager with partial rendering enabled, once I disabled this the page_load function triggers, as well as the click function.